# Hide Div Based on Contents Of Other Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div which contains a variable, which is the category of the item in display, as well as a div containing a link to a size chart like so:

```
<div class="category">Costume</div>

<div class="chart"> <a id="SizeChart"   href="http://http://shopping.netsuite.com/partycentre" target="_blank">Size Chart</a></div></div>
```

I would like to display the size chart div only if the the category is "costume" - I've tried the following script but it's not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
if($('.category').html() == Costume) {
    $('.chart').css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $('.jkmart').css('display', 'none');
}
 });  
  </script>
```

***EDIT: Thank you all for your replies, the fix was a  minor issue with the syntax around "Costume"

Comment: your console should have complain about an undefined variable, no?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Costume` is a string literal so it needs to be enclosed within `''` or `""`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.category').html() == 'Costume') {
        $('.chart').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $('.jkmart').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

if you look at your browser console it should have a reference error for the Costume variable

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should add quotation marks to Costume in the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
if($('.category').html() == "Costume") {
    $('.chart').css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $('.jkmart').css('display', 'none');
}
 });  
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($('.category').html() == 'Costume') {
        $('.chart').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $('.jkmart').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change "Costume" to "Costume1" and try below code

```
 if($('.category').html() == "Costume") {
      $('.chart').css('display', 'block');
 } else {
      $('.chart').css('display', 'none');
 }
```